# Mailgun webhooks: "HTTPS certificate validation failure" after renewing SSL certificte

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, mailgun

Shortly after we renewed our SSL certificate on Heroku, all Mailgun webhooks (post requests made by Mailgun to our endpoint so that we can track email deliveries) started failing with the error "Could not connect to remote server: HTTPS certificate validation failure".

How could we check whether this issue might be caused from misconfiguration of our SSL certificate rather than an issue on Mailgun's side?

Here are the details of steps we took to renew and install the certificate:

- We followed [these instructions](https://www.resumonk.com/blog/setup-ssl-certificate-heroku/) to generate a new private key and
  CSR.
- After uploading the CSR and downloading the CRT file on Namecheap, we ran `heroku certs:update` as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#update-certificate).

These are the checks we made to verify successful installation of the new certificate:

- Navigated to our site with Chrome, Safari, and Firefox and checked
  the certificates. Everything looks right.
- Ran `heroku certs`. The certificate looks good and it is shown as `trusted`.
- Used the online checker [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) and [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) (as watery suggested in the comments). Everything is green.
- Verified with Namecheap that the intermediates were setup correctly. They basically confirmed that the output of `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.mysite.com:443` looks right.

A potential lead:

- After running `brew update openssl` and `rvm install 2.3.1 --disable-binary`, the following was observed. Running `Net::HTTP.get URI('https://www.google.com')` works, while the same command with our URL fails with `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed`.
- However, running `Net::HTTP.get` for our URL on a freshly installed linux Docker container
  does not fail, so there may be additional environment factors.

Any leads to the likely cause of this issue, or suggestions for steps we can take to find such lead, are much appreciated.

Comment: The [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) by SSL Labs seems to go more in-depth, could be worth a try.

Comment: Also - if I'm not confusing Namecheap with another provider - did you set up the new certificate together with any intermediate certificate they provided you?

Comment: Thanks watery. I ran the test you suggested and got an overall rating of "A+" with most green (only red issues were related to IE 6). Regarding the intermediate certificate - no I did not set up intermediate certificates. Thanks for pointing that out .I'll check with them whether this was necessary or not.

Comment: I talked with Namecheap support and they confirmed that our intermediates are configured correctly..

Answer (score 0):

The issue was found as described in [my other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966650/ruby-nethttp-responds-with-opensslsslsslerror-certificate-verify-failed). COMODO added a new root called `COMODO RSA Certification Authority` instead of the previous `COMODO Certification Authority`. The new root was not whitelisted by Mailgun. I contacted support, and they are working to whitelist it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to SSL chaining issue. Please check the ssl certificate you are using must be in order of domain_cert > root_cert > intermediate_cert(they can be multiple). You need to concat certificate in fixed order to fix this issue. I hope this helps you. For more you can test you website ssl in this https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/